# Scala TestOnly and @DoNotDiscover

Tags: scala, scalatest

I am working on a project which is written in Scala and uses ScalaTest for unit testing.

The way tests are structured is that all tests are wrapped in Suites. Individual test case classes are decorated with attribute `@DoNotDiscover` so that when someone runs `sbt test` only the suite gets run and individual classes are not run on their own. The suite then executes all test cases which are a part of it.

This is pretty good however one side effect of this is that if I do `sbt test-only com.IndividualTestCase` then I get output

```
[info] Run completed in 1 second, 142 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 0
[info] Suites: completed 0, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 0, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] No tests were executed.
[info] No tests to run for test:testOnly
```

What I want is that if someone says `sbt test` then only the suite gets executed and classes with `@DoNotDiscover` don't get executed.

But if I specifically call out my test case like `sbt test-only com.IndividualTestCase` then SBT is able to find and execute only the specific test case which was specified.

It seems that if classes are marked with `@DoNotDiscover` then we loose the ability to do `test-only` on individual test cases (I can do test-only on the suite easily)

The [documentation](http://www.artima.com/docs-scalatest-2.0.M5/org/scalatest/DoNotDiscover.html) says that `ScalaTest will run classes annotated with DoNotDiscover if asked to explicitly, it just won't discover them.` But that did not happen for me. As you can see above, the test-only command on the individual test case did not run any tests.